# OpenCL variable declaration failed outside kernel scope

Tags: c, function, kernel, opencl

I am trying to maintain a kernel wise global variable that can act like a static variable. So that I can have the previous value store in the variable for further calculations.
Here is what I tried and what I got as an error:

```
__global int weightsum;
__kernel void calcLWMALoop(int begin, int limit, __global double *price, __global double *firstValue, int weightsum)
          {
            int len = get_global_id(3);
            for(int i=begin;i<limit;i++)
            {                 
               weightsum+=(i-begin+1);
               firstValue[len]+=(i-begin+1)*price[i];
            }
      firstValue[len]/=(double)weightsum;

          }
```

The output error was:

```
OpenCL program create failed: INVALID_HANDLE <kernel>:41:14: error: variable has address space that is not supported in program scope declaration
__global int weightsum;
             ^
<kernel>:41:14: error: global variables must have a constant address space qualifier
5105
```

The `5105` error code says:  `Error occurred when compiling an OpenCL program`

Let me know what I can do in this situation. Please suggest me a proper way so can program efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

You can have program scope or static variables in `__global` address space, but only in OpenCL 2.0. You can pass `-cl-std=CL2.0` to `clBuildProgram` to enable this, if your OpenCL implementation (a driver) have OpenCL 2.0 support.

Related quotes from the spec:

OpenCL 1.x:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/global.html

> All program scope variables must be declared in the __constant address space.

OpenCL 2.0: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/global.html

> Variables defined at program scope and static variables inside a function can also be declared in the global address space. They can be defined with any valid OpenCL C data type except for those in table 6.3. In particular, such program scope variables may be of any user-defined type, or a pointer to a user-defined type. In the presence of shared virtual memory, these pointers or pointer members should work as expected as long as they are shared virtual memory pointers and the referenced storage has been mapped appropriately. These variables in the global address space have the same lifetime as the program, and their values persist between calls to any of the kernels in the program. These variables are not shared across devices. They have distinct storage.
>
> Program scope and static variables in the global address space may be initialized, but only with constant expressions.
>
> The const qualifier can also be used with the __global qualifier to specify a read-only buffer memory object.

Comment: Where and how I can pass `-cl-std=CL2.0` to `clBuildProgram`? I am using Opencl in `MQL5`.

Comment: Based on what I see here (https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/opencl/clprogramcreate), there is no way to pass additional compile options using MQL5, but I'm not an expert in MQL5, so you might find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have global variables in OpenCL C kernel language.
You can create a host buffer (clCreateBuffer) and pass it to the kernel (clSetKernelArg), and then it becomes a pointer to global in your kernel. 
You can also create pointers to global in private memory, but that is visible only per work-item.

Comment: Does this means that I cannot have a global variable outside kernel? can I declare like this: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/global.html But this one didn't helped me.

Comment: As he said, "You cannot have global variables in OpenCL C kernel language." It is correct. The __global address qualifier is for pointers. Use a buffer to hold values that all work items need access to. Also, `get_global_id(3)` does not seem valid; you can only access 0 to 2.